# Common Table Expressions

Tags: oracle-12c, cte

Are there alternatives to common table expressions in Oracle 12 c? I'v been using the syntax from SQL Server and oracle gives me the following error.

```
SELECT CTE_TEST AS (SELECT DISTINCT deptno, ename
        FROM   Test_Table  )
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Error at Command Line : 43 Column : 20
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: How about trying to select from your CTE?

Comment: Of course that will error out because there is no table alias `e` and `select * from cte` is missing

Comment: @Kumar  Still doesn't work

Comment: @TomV tried it. Didn't help

Comment: OK you changed the query and error entirely now. there is no CTE, it's CTE_TEST

Comment: Remove first key word `select` and add `with`

Comment: `with cte_test as ( SELECT DISTINCT deptno, ename
        FROM   Test_Table)  select * from cte_test;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> with cte_test
      2  as
      3  (select * from emp);
    (select * from emp)
                      *
    ERROR at line 3:
    ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword


    SQL> select cte_test as (select * from emp)
      2  select * from cte;
    select cte_test as (select * from emp)
                       *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


    SQL> with cte_test as (select * from emp)
      2  select * from cte_test;

         EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
    ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 1980-12-17 00:00:00        800                    20
          7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-20 00:00:00       1600        300         30
          7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-22 00:00:00       1250        500         30
          7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 1981-04-02 00:00:00       2975                    20
          7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-28 00:00:00       1250       1400         30
          7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 1981-05-01 00:00:00       2850                    30
          7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 1981-06-09 00:00:00       2450                    10
          7839 KING       PRESIDENT            1981-11-17 00:00:00       5000                    10
          7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-08 00:00:00       1500          0         30
          7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 1981-12-03 00:00:00        950                    30
          7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 1981-12-03 00:00:00       3000                    20
          7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 1982-01-23 00:00:00       1300                    10

    12 rows selected.

    SQL>
```